# Remove Outline on Right-clicked Rows in SwiftUI Mac App List

Tags: swiftui, nstableview, swiftui-list, nstableviewcell, nstablerowview

I'm building a macOS app with SwiftUI, and I'm trying to remove (or even cover up) the border added to a `List` item when I right-click it.

Here it is by default:

[image: List Row]

Now with a right-click and a `contextMenu` view modifier:

[image: List Row Right Click]

I figured this is an `NSTableView` quirk, so I tried the approaches in these three Stack Overflow posts:

1. [Customize right click highlight on view-based NSTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619664/customize-right-click-highlight-on-view-based-nstableview)
2. [NSTableView with menu, how to change the border color with right click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789307/nstableview-with-menu-how-to-change-the-border-color-with-right-click?noredirect=1&lq=1)
3. [Disabling the NSTableView row focus ring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30589230/disabling-the-nstableview-row-focus-ring?noredirect=1&lq=1)
4. [NSTableView: blue outline on right-clicked rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219764/nstableview-blue-outline-on-right-clicked-rows?rq=1)

I couldn't get any of those to work, and that may be due to the fact that I can't subclass an `NSTableView`, but can only override its properties and methods with an `extension`. Here's what I have so far that successfully removes the default table background and such:

```
extension NSTableView{
  open override func viewDidMoveToWindow() {
    super.viewDidMoveToWindow()

    //Remove default table styles
    backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
    enclosingScrollView!.drawsBackground = false
    selectionHighlightStyle = .none
  }
}
```

Is there any way to remove that right-click border in SwiftUI? I'm even open to covering it with other views, but I can't seem to draw SwiftUI views in that space around the table cell.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: @EuanTraynor I found a workaround. I'll post it as an answer since it contains some code.

Comment: thanks for the extension of NSTableView! I have no idea how AppKit works but I was struggling to simply remove the default selection highlight... SwiftUI solutions (especially .listRowBackground(Color.clear)) work well for iOS and iPadOS but on AppKit is stubborn...

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this. I put my `List` in a `ZStack` and then set its `opacity` to zero. I then built out a fully custom version of the same list, but using `LazyVStack`:

```
//Message List
ZStack{
  //Ghost list for keyboard control
  List($model.messages, id: \.self, selection: $model.selectedMessages){ $message in
    MessageItemView(message: $message)
  }
  .focusable()
  .opacity(0)
  
  //Custom UI for the above List
  ScrollView{
    ZStack{ 
      LazyVStack(spacing: 5){
        ForEach($model.messagesToday){ $message in
          MessageItemView(message: $message)
        }
      }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
  }
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
```

Each list is bound to the same model, so if I click a `message` to select it in the custom UI, the same thing gets selected in the invisible `List`. All the keyboard shortcuts that come with table use in a `List` look like they are working on the custom version.

So how does this solve my original problem? You can right-click on the custom `MessageItemView` and the default ring around the cell is invisible, but the `contextMenu` still works (it's defined inside my `MessageItemView`).

This isn't as elegant as I'd like, but it's nice to have 100% control over the UI but still get all the keyboard controls that come for free with a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSTableView.selectionIsChangingNotification)) { notification in
  if let tableView = notification.object as? NSTableView {
    tableView.selectionHighlightStyle = .none
  }
}
```

You can use this. It will reload your List. I'm looking for another approach but this works.